# How can I retrieve a file object from the blobstore within a handler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I've saved a document in the blobstore, and am trying to retrieve it within a handler (which handles a task). I've had a read of [the appengine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview) regarding the how to use blobstore, but am struggling to get it to work for my case. I've tried the following within the handler but cannot seem to have the object returned as the saved file (e.g. .pdf or .txt)

```
class SendDocuments(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        document_key = self.request.get("document_key")
        document_key = Key(str(document_key))
        the_document = DocumentsModel.all().filter("__key__ =", document_key).get()
        file_data = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(str(the_document.blobstore_key)) # returns a blobinfo object
        file_data.open() # returns a blobreader object
        file_data.open().read() # returns a string
```

I've also tried

```
class ServeSavedDocument(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, blob_key):
    self.send_blob(blob_key, save_as=True)
    return

class SendDocuments(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        document_key = self.request.get("document_key")
        document_key = Key(str(document_key))
        the_document = DocumentsModel.all().filter("__key__ =", document_key).get()
        grab_blob = ServeSavedDocument()
        file_data = grab_blob.get(self, str(the_document.blobstore_key))
```

But the call to ServeSavedDocument fails with

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'headers'
```

I've had a look at the [files api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) but the only example that's not saving the file simply seems to return the blob key i.e.

```
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

What is the best way to grab a saved file in the blobstore from within a handler?

### EDIT 1:

I'm trying to retrieve the txt file or pdf file from the blobstore in a format / state that can be encoded as a file in a post request using the following code

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
# assuming here that file_data is the file object
payload = {}
payload['user_id'] = '1234123412341234'
payload['test_file'] = MultipartParam('test_file', filename=file_data.filename,
                                      filetype=file_data.type,
                                      fileobj=file_data.file)
data,headers= multipart_encode(payload)
send_url = "http://127.0.0.0/"
t = urlfetch.fetch(url=send_url, payload="".join(data), method=urlfetch.POST, headers=headers)
```

Comment: What do you mean "have the object returned as the saved file"? A file is just a container for data; the blobstore APIs return that data. And are you trying to serve the blob to the user, or use the data in your app? The former has a complete working example in the blobstore docs; have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Nick, I've got to grips with how to have the blobstore return a blob to the user by going through the documentation. What I'm trying to do is grab a textfile stored in blobstore and ship it off to an external (file processing API) by encoding the file in a multipart post request using the python poster library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of messing around I"ve found that this works! The key was to simply call open() on the blobinfo object.

```
class SendDocuments(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        document_key = self.request.get("document_key")
        document_key = Key(str(document_key))
        the_document = DocumentsModel.all().filter("__key__ =", document_key).get()
        file_data = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(str(the_document.blobstore_key))
        payload = {}
        payload['user_id'] = '1234123412341234'
        payload['test_file'] = MultipartParam('the_file', filename="something",
                                      filetype=file_data.content_type,
                                      fileobj=file_data.open())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the BlobReader class, I think that's what you are looking for:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass

It allows file-like read access to blobstore data:

```
# blob_key = ..

# Instantiate a BlobReader for a given Blobstore value.
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
# Read the entire value into memory. This may take a while depending
# on the size of the value and the size of the read buffer, and is not
# recommended for large values.
value = blob_reader.read()
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried this, however value is returned as a string but I need it to be a file like object such that it is suitable for a multipart post encoding - see Edit 1 above :)

Comment: What's your definition of file-like object? blobstore.BlobReader is the closest you get to a file object has it is generally known in the context of Python (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: Hi there, apologies for any lacking explanation - I'm still learning :) Semantics aside my goal is to find a way to encode the file with in a multipart post request - I've given an example in the first edit in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try as this,specify the file name and it's type in the `send_blob()` as :

```
def mime_type(filename):
    return guess_type(filename)[0]
    class ServeSavedDocument(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
        def get(self):
            blob_key = self.request.get("blob_key")
            if blob_key:
                blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)               
                if blob_info:
                    save_as1 =  blob_info.filename
                    type1=mime_type(blob_info.filename)
                    self.send_blob(blob_info,content_type=type1,save_as=save_as1)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the code. Assuming you meant to have the class at the same indentation level as def mime_type I've attempted to implement this however type1 gets returned as None. Also self.send_blob fails with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'headers'.